# Rational Team Concert install to RAD v9.1.0 does not show Accept Team Invitation in File menu

Tags: rtc, ibm-rad

I have installed Rational Team Concert (RTC-Client-p2Repo-4.0.6.zip) to my RAD v9.1.0 install on Mac OS.  The install had no errors or issues and it asked to restart RAD to make sure the change takes affect.

I restarted RAD and in the File menu, there is no "Accept Team Invitation" selection.  I restarted my MacBook itself and it still does appear.

I tried to install Rational Team Concert again, but it gives me a message it will not install because it already has been installed.

I checked the error log and I found no errors during the install.

Is there a way to uninstall Rational Team Concert (tried IBM Installation Manager, but does not appear in that) and possibly reinstall?

Any help would be great - thanks!

Comment: Did you try to switch to the "Work Items" perspective? Also check http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=3488&uid=swg21391033 (just in case, since it is for a different product)

Comment: If it does not help, just look also for <your-workspace>/.metadata/.log files whether there are any errors.

Comment: @VonC - I don't have the Work Items perspective and the link did not help me out.  I don't have an "Advanced" button on the Team preferences.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @kazik1616 - I have been going over the error.log, but nothing has to do with Rational Team Concert.  I will look for any other errors.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dan That should mean RTC haven't been properly detected/installed on RAD then

Comment: I would suggest you opening new ticket (PMR) for the support

Answer (score 0):

Install RTC Client in the same work space as of RAD